# How to display a database dynamically generated list of options which shows the current value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've created a program which allows you to click a book you wish to edit from a table. You can then choose to update the book's contents from a form which has been dynamically created.

I can echo out the book values to the user fine but when it comes to putting them into a drop down list of options I'm running into issues.

So I'm trying to display a drop down list of categories and publishers which can be changed by the user but when loaded will populate with the correct information

Code for creating the table

```
$sql = "SELECT bookISBN
             , bookTitle
             , bookYear
             , bookPrice
             , catDesc 
          FROM nbl_books b
          JOIN nbl_category c
            on c.catID = b.catID
         ORDER 
            BY bookTitle
    ";

$queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);
    if($queryResult->rowcount() > 0){
        echo "<table class='table-bordered table-striped'>"; //bootstrap class
            echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>Title</th>";
                    echo "<th>Year</th>";
                    echo "<th>Category</th>";
                    echo "<th>Price</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>"; //Tableheading end
            echo "<tbody>";
            while ($rowObj = $queryResult->fetchObject()){ 
                $rowObj->booktitle = filter_var($rowObj->bookTitle, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
                $rowObj->booktitle = filter_var($rowObj->bookTitle, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

                $rowObj->bookISBN = filter_var($rowObj->bookISBN, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
                $rowObj->bookISBN = filter_var($rowObj->bookISBN, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

                $rowObj->bookYear = filter_var($rowObj->bookYear, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
                $rowObj->bookYear = filter_var($rowObj->bookYear, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

                $rowObj->catDesc = filter_var($rowObj->catDesc, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
                $rowObj->catDesc = filter_var($rowObj->catDesc, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);


                $rowObj->bookPrice = filter_var($rowObj->bookPrice, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
                $rowObj->bookPrice = filter_var($rowObj->bookPrice, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><a href='update.php?bookISBN={$rowObj->bookISBN}'> {$rowObj->bookTitle} </a></td>";
                echo "<td> $rowObj->bookYear </td>";
                echo "<td> $rowObj->catDesc </td>";
                echo "<td> $rowObj->bookPrice </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
            unset($queryResult);


    } else {
        echo "no records found";
    }

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "<p>Query failed: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n";
}
```

[image: List of books]

Displaying the first three editable values to the user

```
<form id='updatebook' action='updateMovie.php' method='get'>

<?php 
//BookTitle passed by hyperlink
$bookISBN = $_GET['bookISBN'];


if (empty($bookISBN)) {
    echo "<p>Please <a href='welcome.php'>choose</a> a movie.</p>\n";
}
else {
    try {
        require_once ("functions.php");
        $dbConn = getConnection(); 

$sql = "SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, bookPrice -- catDesc, pubName
        FROM nbl_books
        -- INNER JOIN nbl_category
        -- ON nbl_category.catID = nbl_books.catID
        -- INNER JOIN nbl_publisher
        -- ON nbl_publisher.pubID = nbl_publisher.pubID
        WHERE bookISBN = $bookISBN";
        
        $queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);

        $rowObj = $queryResult->fetchObject();
        
        echo "
        <h1>Update '{$rowObj->bookTitle}'</h1>
        
            <p>Title <input type='text' name='title' size='50' value='{$rowObj->bookTitle}' /></p>
            <p>Book year <input type='text' name='bookYear' value='{$rowObj->bookYear}' /></p>
            <p>Book Price <input type='text' name='bookPrice' value='{$rowObj->bookPrice}' /></p> ";
            ?>
```

[image]

Now here is where I'm running into issues.

On the first drop-down you can see the category is correct but I can't display the other options

Category

```
<select name="categoryID">
<?php   

        $sqlCat = "SELECT nbl_category.catID, catDesc, bookISBN
        from nbl_category
        INNER JOIN nbl_books
        ON nbl_books.catID = nbl_category.catID
        WHERE bookISBN = $bookISBN
        ORDER BY catDesc";

        
        $nblCat = $dbConn->query($sqlCat);

        while ($catRecord = $nblCat->fetchObject()) {
            echo "<option value='{$catRecord->catID}'> {$catRecord->catDesc}</option>";
        }; 
?>
    </select>
```

[image]

In this other drop-down, you can see the publisher although this is not the correct value it's just the first one in the database table but the while loop succesfully iterates through the other publishers so there is other options.

```
<select name="PublisherID">
    <?php   
    
                $sqlPub = "SELECT pubID, pubName 
                from nbl_publisher 
                ORDER BY pubName";
                
                $nblPub = $dbConn->query($sqlPub);

                while ($pubRecord = $nblPub->fetchObject()) {
                    echo "<option value='{$pubRecord->pubID}'>{$pubRecord->pubName}</option>";
                }; 
    ?>
            </select> <br>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your category drop-down filling query should not be limited to your current book's ISBN. Try this:

```
<select name="categoryID">
<?php   

        $sqlCat = "
SELECT nbl_category.catID
     , catDesc
     , IF(nbl_books.bookISBN = $bookISBN, 1, 0) as isCurrentCategory
  FROM nbl_category
  LEFT 
  JOIN nbl_books 
    ON nbl_books.catID = nbl_category.catID 
   AND nbl_books.bookISBN = $bookISBN
 ORDER 
    BY catDesc
";

        
        $nblCat = $dbConn->query($sqlCat);

        while ($catRecord = $nblCat->fetchObject()) {
            $selected = $catRecord->isCurrentCategory ? 'selected' : '';
            echo "<option value='{$catRecord->catID}' {$selected}> {$catRecord->catDesc}</option>";
        }; 
?>
    </select>
```

For your publisher drop-down, you almost got it right. Only you don't have the publisher for the book you are displaying. You could use the same strategy proposed above:

```
<select name="PublisherID">
    <?php   
    
                $sqlPub = "
SELECT nbl_publisher.pubID
     , nbl_publisher.pubName
     , IF(nbl_books.bookISBN = $bookISBN, 1, 0) as isCurrentPublisher
  FROM nbl_publisher
  LEFT 
  JOIN nbl_books 
    ON nbl_books.pubID = nbl_publisher.pubID 
   AND nbl_books.bookISBN = $bookISBN
 ORDER 
    BY pubName
";
                
                $nblPub = $dbConn->query($sqlPub);

                while ($pubRecord = $nblPub->fetchObject()) {
                    $selected = $pubRecord->isCurrentPublisher ? 'selected' : '';
                    echo "<option value='{$pubRecord->pubID}' {$selected}>{$pubRecord->pubName}</option>";
                }; 
    ?>
            </select> <br>
```

**EDIT:**

And, as suggested by Strawberry, you should take care of SQL injection, and PDO adds some benefits like parameters as templates. See [this tutorial for further information](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Comment: That worked, thanks for sharing the code I can clearly see where I was going wrong and I have learned a lot more about SQL statements in the process. That document you shared is very usefull and it's what I needed!